# How to Change the Logo in a Laravel Jetstream Application

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-jetstream

I am new to Laravel and am trying to change the logo in a Laravel application with Jetstream and Inertia.

I have gone over the documentation as well as resources on Laracasts and understand that I need to update the svg (or can use a png/jpg etc by using the html img tag) in the following files:

- application-logo.blade.php
- authentication-card-logo.blade.php
- application-mark.blade.php

The Logo is referenced in AppLayout.vue via a jet-application-mark element:

```
<div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center">
    <inertia-link :href="route('dashboard')">
        <jet-application-mark class="block h-9 w-auto" />
    </inertia-link>
</div>
```

As well as a jet-application-logo element in the Welcome.vue:

```
<div>
    <jet-application-logo class="block h-12 w-auto" />
</div>
```

In each of the files listed above I replaced the svg with an html img to a resource:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/enhanced-logo.png') }}" />
```

After changing the files above and rebuilding, the original Jetstream logo remains - the only place that it is working is in login.blade.php, the following code does pull in the image that I want:

```
<x-slot name="logo">
    <x-jet-authentication-card-logo />
</x-slot>
```

Any direction as to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Try clearing the cached views `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: That didn't do it, still the Jetstream logo.

Comment: Try disabling browser cache  - for chrome devtools > network tab  - check Disable cache

Comment: Thanks, tried that - still not working.

Comment: Just noticed that you are using inertia stack - for that you have to replace the logo in `authentication-card-logo.blade.php` which you have so it's showing on login page. But for the other places you need to update in `resources/js/Jetstream/ApplicationLogo.vue` and `resources/js/Jetstream/ApplicationMark.vue`

Comment: Yes that was it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change logo in a Laravel Jetstream application:

The authentication views in a Jetstream application, regardless of the stack are simple blade views common for both stacks. To change the logo for authentication views edit `resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/authentication-card-logo.blade.php`

```
<a href="/">
    //Replace the default svg with your own logo svg or an image
    <img src="custom/logo.png" />
</a>
```

Then depending upon the stack

**Inertia stack**

Replace the default logo with your own custom logo in

- resources/js/Jetstream/ApplicationLogo.vue
- resources/js/Jetstream/ApplicationMark.vue

with

```
<template>
    //Replace the default svg with your own logo svg or an image
    <img src="custom/logo.png" />
</template>
```

**Livewire stack**

Replace the default logo with your own custom logo in

- resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/application-logo.blade.php
- resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/application-mark.blade.php

with

```
//Replace the default svg with your own logo svg or an image
<img src="custom/logo.png" />
```

Comment: I have issue, if i navigate to /user/profile page (jetstream teams), path to my logo images is host/team/img/logo.png , but e.g. from /dashboard page logo is working and the path is host/img/logo.png

Comment: How does the src of image change? Or is it that you want to change the logo for team? Profile show view includes application-mark.blade.php so what ever image you replace in application-mark.blade.php will show up there

Comment: Firstly, if i change application-mark.blade.php nothing changes, but changes only when i modify resources/js/Jetstream/ApplicationMark.vue. And i dont know why src is changing, maybe its related to vue router or something...

Comment: oh i got, i have itertia stack, but why img/logo.png works relative to my navigation position i cant understand

Comment: Sorry I just assumed that you are on Livewire stack. Change the logos for Inertia stack as mentioned above and things should work. The authentication views share the common views in both stacks so on auth related views the new logo will appear once you change it in resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/authentication-card-logo.blade.php

Comment: No, its not working. If i navigate to localhost/project/public/dashboard i got  localhost/project/public/img/logo.png, but if i navigate to localhost/project/public/user/profile image link become localhost/project/public/user/img/logo.png. On production /img/logo.png will do the trick, but how to make working on my local env

Comment: Don't know how the segment /user is getting introduced. Try using relative path on local env as well `/img/logo.png` and recompile js

Comment: if i will use /img/logo.png it will be localhost/public/, but i have several projects under localhost

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that I am using the Inertia stack, I needed to edit the following files:

- resources/js/Jetstream/ApplicationLogo.vue
- resources/js/Jetstream/ApplicationMark.vue

With:

```
<template>
      <img src="/images/enhanced-logo.png"/>
</template>
```

As well as the file:

- resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/authentication-card-logo.blade.php

With:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/enhanced-logo.png') }}" />
```

To replace the existing Jetstream logo with my image.

Comment: i cant set <img src="/images/enhanced-logo.png"/> , because on my computer / is localhost, but i have different projects

Comment: and if i navigate to /user/profile page (jetstream teams), path to my logo images is host/team/img/logo.png , but e.g. from /dashboard page logo is working and the path is host/img/logo.png

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel 10 and Livewire it is located in

resources/views/components/authentication-card-logo.blade.php